# How to detect hardware keyboard presence?

Tags: android, keyboard, hardware, device

Is there a way to detect if the device I'm currently running on has a hardware keyboard installed?

How do I query device capabilities anyway?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

[[android-developers] Re: Detect Physical Keyboard
Layout (ex: QWERTY vs QWERTZ)](https://web.archive.org/web/20120106045151/http://osdir.com/ml/AndroidDevelopers/2009-06/msg00486.html)

> The flags provided by [getResources().getConfiguration().keyboard](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Configuration#keyboard) are a
> good way of checking which keyboard (if any) is available.

Comment: Basically that means:



    private boolean isHardwareKeyboardAvailable() {
       return getResources().getConfiguration().keyboard != Configuration.KEYBOARD_NOKEYS;
    }

Comment: Yes, if for your purposes you are counting a "12-key keyboard" as a "hardware keyboard".

Comment: Note it will detect a keyboard that is an integral part of the device, but it will not detect if a USB or Bluetooth keyboard is currently attached. See https://stackoverflow.com/q/12161989/11683 for that.

Answer (score 5):

To detect common qwerty keyboard connected use this:

```
private boolean isKeyboardConnected() {
    return getResources().getConfiguration().keyboard == KEYBOARD_QWERTY;
}
```

Comment: For those wondering, it's Configuration.KEYBOARD_QWERTY

Answer (score 4):

Use the following method to ascertain presence of hard keyboard at any time:
(To my knowledge, soft keyboards all *lack* the features tested below )

```
public static boolean isHardKB(Context ctx) {
    Configuration cf = ctx.getResources().getConfiguration();
    return cf.navigation==Configuration.NAVIGATION_DPAD
        || cf.navigation==Configuration.NAVIGATION_TRACKBALL
        || cf.navigation==Configuration.NAVIGATION_WHEEL;
}
```

Optionally trap *all* run-time keyboard changes for each affected Activity via *AndroidManifest*:

```
android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|navigation"
```

But be sure to support the above manifest change with (at least) a dummy **onConfigurationChanged()**

```
@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    // Optionally employ 'isHardKB()'   
}
```

Comment: What I can see cf.navigation relates to the virtual keyboard and not the physical keyboard, when I try a physical BT-keybord with keypad? But it can be a keyboard driver mistake? (The HAXM emulators says no keypad but keypad input works?) SO far I can only see as the article HostileForks answer relates to that Config.hardKeyboardHidden == Configuration.HARDKEYBOARDHIDDEN_NO detects if HW keyboard is present.