# Finding if external usb or bluetooth keyboard attached in Android

Tags: android, keyboard

Can anyone please tell me if there is any way we can find out if a bluetooth QWERTY keyboard is attached to android device.

I tried working with [getResources().getConfiguration.keyboard](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Configuration#keyboard), but it always gives me the same value whether key board is attached or not.

Thanks

Answer (score 18, accepted):

One way to do this is adding `android:configChanges="keyboard"` to the activity in your AndroidManifest.xml file.

With this you can override  `onConfigurationChanged` which will be called whenever a keyboard is plugged in or plugged out

```
 @Override
 public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) 
 {
   if(newConfig.hardKeyboardHidden == Configuration.HARDKEYBOARDHIDDEN_NO) {
        //A hardware keyboard is being connected
   }  
   else if(newConfig.hardKeyboardHidden == Configuration.HARDKEYBOARDHIDDEN_YES)
       //A hardware keyboard is being disconnected
   }

 }
```

Comment: Only works for me if I use android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden". I'm on Android N Preview

Comment: Does this work if the user connects the keyboard before starting the app?

Comment: Well the question should be made in the onCreate as well because the onConfigurationChanged is not called by start. I made a method to be called.

Answer (score 0):

An improvement to @LeonLucardie's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12162358/3501958), in Kotlin.

Manifest (as per @MobileMon's comment):

```
<activity
    android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden"
```

Activity:

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

    when (resources.configuration.hardKeyboardHidden) {
        HARDKEYBOARDHIDDEN_NO -> Log.d(TAG, "A hardware keyboard is connected.")
        HARDKEYBOARDHIDDEN_YES -> Log.d(TAG, "A hardware keyboard is disconnected.")
    }
}

override fun onConfigurationChanged(newConfig: Configuration) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig)

    when (newConfig.hardKeyboardHidden) {
        HARDKEYBOARDHIDDEN_NO -> Log.d(TAG, "A hardware keyboard is being connected.")
        HARDKEYBOARDHIDDEN_YES -> Log.d(TAG, "A hardware keyboard is being disconnected.")
    }
}
```

Note: calling `super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig)` seems to be mandatory.