# How detect if hardware keyboard in Android devices?

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android

I need to detect if an Android device has the physical keyboard.  I am using `Resources.Configuration.Keyboard` but it always returns `Android.Content.Res.KeyboardType.Nokeys`. For testing I am using a real Android device with hardware keyboard. What I am missing?

Platform: Xamarin Android

Comment: If you test on another real devices and emulators with hardware keyboard will you get the same result?

Answer (score 0):

[Finding if external usb or bluetooth keyboard attached in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12161989/finding-if-external-usb-or-bluetooth-keyboard-attached-in-android)

```
 @Override
 public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) 
 {
   if(newConfig.hardKeyboardHidden == Configuration.HARDKEYBOARDHIDDEN_NO) {
        //A hardware keyboard is being connected
   }  
   else if(newConfig.hardKeyboardHidden == Configuration.HARDKEYBOARDHIDDEN_YES)
       //A hardware keyboard is being disconnected
   }

 }
```

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Configuration.html#keyboard