# Detect input from a real keyboard

Tags: android, keyboard

I'm looking for a method to recognize a real input from a real keyboard.
I'm using Android Studio.
I already know that the keyboard is attached to my device.
When I press a key I would like to listen to it and do a specific action.
For example when I press the "B" I want to invoke an Intent, when I press "P" I want to play a video and other things like this.
Thanks a lot

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Finding if external usb or bluetooth keyboard attached in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12161989/finding-if-external-usb-or-bluetooth-keyboard-attached-in-android)

Comment: Is not a duplicate because I already know that the Keyboard is attached, I would like to listen for a specific key pressed

Comment: Then all you have to do is set an `OnKeyListener` to the appropriate view.