# How to tell whether an android device has hard keys

Tags: android

How can I tell whether an android device has physical keys or the software navigation bar?  I need to change the layout dependant on whether the software navigation is drawn.

For example the HTC Desire C has hardware keys:
[image]

I should clarify - Im looking at the navigation bar, not the keyboard.  Home, back etc. I've tried:

```
        getResources().getConfiguration().keyboard);
        getResources().getConfiguration().navigation);
        getResources().getConfiguration().navigationHidden);
```

return the same values on both devices.

Comment: Duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2415558/how-to-detect-hardware-keyboard-presence

Answer (score 55):

Solved by doing this the first time the app is launched and saving to preferences:

```
public static boolean hasSoftKeys(WindowManager windowManager){
    boolean hasSoftwareKeys = true;
    //c = context; use getContext(); in fragments, and in activities you can 
    //directly access the windowManager();

    if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT>=Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR1){
        Display d = c.getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();

        DisplayMetrics realDisplayMetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
        d.getRealMetrics(realDisplayMetrics);

        int realHeight = realDisplayMetrics.heightPixels;
        int realWidth = realDisplayMetrics.widthPixels;

        DisplayMetrics displayMetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
        d.getMetrics(displayMetrics);

        int displayHeight = displayMetrics.heightPixels;
        int displayWidth = displayMetrics.widthPixels;

        hasSoftwareKeys =  (realWidth - displayWidth) > 0 ||
                           (realHeight - displayHeight) > 0;
    } else {
        boolean hasMenuKey = ViewConfiguration.get(c).hasPermanentMenuKey();
        boolean hasBackKey = KeyCharacterMap.deviceHasKey(KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK);
        hasSoftwareKeys = !hasMenuKey && !hasBackKey;
    }
    return hasSoftwareKeys;
}
```

Comment: The method `getRealMetrics` is only available in API 17 (i.e. the Android 4.2) - You're implying that you don't know the device, so you can't really rely on this method being there.

Comment: I agree this method because `ViewConfiguration.get(context).hasPermanentMenuKey()` is tricky on some devices. So when API >= 17, I use this method instead.

Comment: I, too, am now using this technique on devices >= API 17.  Not to be too nit-picky, but your return statement might be a little more readable as: `return (realWidth > displayWidth) || (realHeight > displayHeight)`

Comment: One note: if you do this from a service, and the service accidentally starts while the device is in full screen (i.e Youtube etc..), you'll get the wrong result.

Comment: @benjamindavis you shouldn't nit on SO answers, it will stop ppl answering if they feel their code has to be perfect before posting.

Comment: Tried many solutions of SO, this one worked seamless for me. Thank you.

Comment: Why do you save it to preferences? Is it too expensive operation?

Comment: for me it is not working correctly because on xioami devices user can use permanent menu keys or full screen gesture and I listen this method and haspermanentmenukey method. when I change from menu keys to fullscren gestured value doesnt change

Answer (score 2):

Here you go.. this should do what you want.

```
@SuppressLint("NewApi")
private static boolean hasSoftNavigation(Context context)
{
    if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.ICE_CREAM_SANDWICH){
        return !ViewConfiguration.get(context).hasPermanentMenuKey();
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: The new galaxy s5 doen't have a menu hardqare key and it still uses hard keys as home, recent and back... This is not a good options to use.

Answer (score 2):

Solution based on @serenskye

```
private fun Activity.hasSoftKeys(): Boolean {
    val display = if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.R) {
        display
    } else {
        windowManager.defaultDisplay
    } ?: return true

    val realDisplayMetrics = DisplayMetrics()
    display.getRealMetrics(realDisplayMetrics)

    val realHeight = realDisplayMetrics.heightPixels
    val realWidth = realDisplayMetrics.widthPixels

    val displayMetrics = DisplayMetrics()
    display.getMetrics(displayMetrics)

    val displayHeight = displayMetrics.heightPixels
    val displayWidth = displayMetrics.widthPixels

    return realWidth - displayWidth > 0 || realHeight - displayHeight > 0
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To avoid deprecation of `getMetrics()` as of Android S (API Level 31), you can use `currentWindowMetrics` of the `WindowManager` and do the comparison of real display & the app's window display:

```
    @RequiresApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR1)
    fun Activity.hasSoftNavigationBar(): Boolean {

        val display = if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.R) {
            display
        } else {
            windowManager.defaultDisplay
        } ?: return true

        val displayWidth = Resources.getSystem().displayMetrics.widthPixels
        val displayHeight = Resources.getSystem().displayMetrics.heightPixels

        val realWidth: Int
        val realHeight: Int

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.S) {
            realWidth = windowManager.currentWindowMetrics.bounds.height()
            realHeight = windowManager.currentWindowMetrics.bounds.width()

        } else {
            val realDisplayMetrics = DisplayMetrics()
            display.getRealMetrics(realDisplayMetrics)
            realWidth = realDisplayMetrics.widthPixels
            realHeight = realDisplayMetrics.heightPixels
        }

        return realWidth - displayWidth > 0 || realHeight - displayHeight > 0

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

`private boolean isHardwareKeyboardAvailable() { return getResources().getConfiguration().keyboard != Configuration.KEYBOARD_NOKEYS; }`

In addition, here is more info. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Configuration.html#keyboard

EDIT - To check for physical keyboard

`private boolean isPhysicalKeyboardAvailable() { return getResources().getConfiguration().keyboard == Configuration.KEYBOARD_QWERTY; }`

For more information on the different Configurations view 
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Configuration.html#keyboard

I am sure one of those works.

2nd EDIT -

Check. Already asked.

[Android: Programmatically detect if device has hardware menu button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9044907/android-programatically-detect-if-device-has-hardware-menu-button)

Comment: Nope, see above, I get the same keyboard for both devices! Configuration.KEYBOARD_NOKEYS;

Comment: See the post, I said im not interested in the menu button, modern devices with hard buttons do not have the menu button

Comment: I'd love to upvote this, especially since it solves my problem (determining if a hardware QWERTY keyboard is available), but I think the OP was asking for something different...