# Check if Android device has software or hardware navigation buttons

Tags: android

I'm writing an Android app with a transparent navigation bar. To adjust the layout accordingly, I need to know whether the device has software or hardware buttons.

During my research I came across the following solutions:

```
boolean hasMenuKey = ViewConfiguration.get(context).hasPermanentMenuKey();
```

This approach does not work on some new devices like the Samsung Note 4 or the HTC One which do not have a menu key, but still have hardware buttons.

```
boolean hasBackKey = KeyCharacterMap.deviceHasKey(KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK);
boolean hasHomeKey = KeyCharacterMap.deviceHasKey(KeyEvent.KEYCODE_HOME);
boolean hasHardwareButtons = hasBackKey && hasHomeKey;
```

This does not work as well, because some devices like the Sony Xperia Z3 Compact return true although it has a software navigation bar.

Is there any reliable way to find out whether there are physical buttons or a software navigation bar?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to tell whether an android device has hard keys](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14853039/how-to-tell-whether-an-android-device-has-hard-keys)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14871974/4428462). You can get the real height of the display in pixels, and then get the height available to your app, and figure out if the device has an on-screen navigation bar with these values.

Answer (score 9):

The answer posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14871974/4428462) did the trick. Just for completeness, here is the code I am using now:

```
private static boolean hasImmersive;
private static boolean cached = false;

@SuppressLint ("NewApi")
public static boolean hasImmersive(Context ctx) {

    if (!cached) {
        if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
            hasImmersive = false;
            cached = true;
            return false;
        }
        Display d = ((WindowManager) ctx.getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE)).getDefaultDisplay();

        DisplayMetrics realDisplayMetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
        d.getRealMetrics(realDisplayMetrics);

        int realHeight = realDisplayMetrics.heightPixels;
        int realWidth = realDisplayMetrics.widthPixels;

        DisplayMetrics displayMetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
        d.getMetrics(displayMetrics);

        int displayHeight = displayMetrics.heightPixels;
        int displayWidth = displayMetrics.widthPixels;

        hasImmersive = (realWidth > displayWidth) || (realHeight > displayHeight);
        cached = true;
    }

    return hasImmersive;
}
```