# How to detect if there is virtual navigation bar in different Android mobile phone?

Tags: android, navigationbar

Different android mobile phone has different behaviors of Virtual Navigation Bar in the bottom of the interface. For example Huawei has it. For other mobile phones, they don't have Virtual Navigation Bar. So how can I detect if there is Virtual Navigation Bar in different Android Mobile Phone?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Check if Android device has software or hardware navigation buttons](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28406506/check-if-android-device-has-software-or-hardware-navigation-buttons)

Answer (score 0):

To find if soft navigation is enabled determine the size of the window provided and to set the layout accordingly. There is a very powerful tool called `decorView` that sets the window initially so as to directly implement methods under it. It can be written like this:

```
val decorView = window.decorView
        decorView.systemUiVisibility = (View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE)
```

Write methods under it to put them inside the frame.

Methods you can use like this:

```
 val decorView = window.decorView
            decorView.systemUiVisibility = (View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE)
    mBottomAppBar = findViewById(R.id.bar)
    mBottomAppBar?.setOnMenuItemClickListener{
               when(it.itemId){
                   R.id.itemConfig->showConfigBottomSheetDialogFragment()
```

Found this while trying a ton of methods and tricks and this one is the only one working. Hope it helps.