# How to remove virtual navigation keys, so they are not seen on my app?

Tags: android, samsung-galaxy

One of the screens on my apps displays a fullscreen animation and the virtual navigation keys disturb the experience. If people use a phone with hardware (navigation) keys they will not see the virtual navigation keys, but if they use a phone with soft (virtual navigation keys) keys they will see it. Apps like YouTube have fixed it, so that people also with soft (virtual navigation keys) keys they will not see it. So how can I remove virtual navigation keys, so they are not seen?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you can show/hide navigation by code,

First find whether hard keys present using this method below then show/hide navigation

[How to tell whether an android device has hard keys](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14853039/how-to-tell-whether-an-android-device-has-hard-keys/14871974)

Comment: Thanks, that was useful info about finding out which devices have hard keys. But how do I hide them ?